# NullPointerException, instantiating a Button

Tags: android

This is the method I used to create button dynamically

```
 public void createButton(String butid, String butname) {
      final Button node=new Button(this);
      node.setText(butname);
      node.setHint(butid);
      node.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
      node.setX(150);
      node.setY(150);        
      node.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      frntPage.addView(node);
}
```

This is the logcat I get the error when I try to call the above method from another activity

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:85)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:74)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3570)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3675)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:634)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:99)
        at com.my.familytree.MainActivity.createButton(MainActivity.java:65)
        at com.my.familytree.MainActivity2$1.onClick(MainActivity2.java:81)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Line no 65 is:

```
final Button node=new Button(this);
```

Is there any other method to create a button dynamically from another activity?

Here is the full activity code

```
package com.my.familytree;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ImageButton user;
    Intent i;
    int x=0;
    RelativeLayout frntPage;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);

        frntPage=new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());

        user=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.adduser);
        user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                IDGen.idcheck("first");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void createButton(String butid, String butname) {
        final Button node=new Button(getApplicationContext());
        node.setText(butname);
        node.setHint(butid);
        node.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        node.setX(150);
        node.setY(150);
        node.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        frntPage.addView(node);
    }
}
```

I tried another method to create button

```
public void createButton(String butid, String butname) {
    final Button new_but=new Button(con);
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(200,200,200,200);
    new_but.setX(150);
    new_but.setY(150);
    final RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(this);
    rl.addView(new_but, layoutParams);
}
```

Now I get the same error as before in line 32:
Line 32 is setting an onClickListener to an ImageButton, user

Refer the complete code for more details

Comment: Can you post your logcat... What error are you getting?

Comment: If you get an exception, it would be useful if you also post it.

Comment: Please post your logcat maybe youre not having the context

Comment: Which is line number 65 ?

Comment: When do you call this method?

Comment: @TristanWiley In a button click in MainActivity2

Comment: Try change  this line : `final Button node=new Button(this);` to : `final Button node=new Button(youractivity.this);`

Comment: @Josef Still getting the same error

Comment: Please post the full activity code

Comment: Actually I call the method createButton() in MainActivity2 @line 81 and it is defined in MainActivity

Comment: minor code alignment corrections

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of null pointer in your code is (possibly newViewGroup is null) -

```
node.setLayoutParams(newViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

As others have specified, post your logcat for tracing out exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this line

```
final Button node=new Button(this);
```

To your `onCreate()` method

Comment: I have to create a button whenever I click the button in MainActivity2 If I create the button in onCreate(), it will only be created once, right?

Comment: Is there any other way to create a button from another activity?

Comment: You could create a context and set it to this

Comment: Sorry, could you explain?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get around to replying until now. You can define a context in your onCreate() to replace the (this). Just do something like Context mContext = this;

Comment: Did you use mContext in place of this?

Comment: final Button node=new Button(con);   con is the context